# Uploading larger size file to server from iPhone app

Tags: ios, file-upload, arrays, nsdata, uploading

I am working on an app in which I need to upload larger video file like 500 MB to 1 GB. For uploading larger file I am sending data chunk by chunk to server.But problem in that is I have to send chunk data by converting it into byte array like below:

const unsigned char *bytes = [dataWithChunk bytes];

```
for (int j = 0; j < dataWithChunk.length; j++)
{
    [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedChar:bytes[j]]];
}
```

This conversion from bytes into array of bytes takes so much time and it adds large amount of delay in my file uploading process. Can anyone have optimized code or better approach for that?